# chosen multiselect hide show error

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, jquery-chosen

Hi i am having trouble in customizing choser jquery multiselect option. my requirement is to hide and show multi select option on click of radio button

[image]

by default it should be hidden and on click of Specialty it should be visible. Any idea?

select html code

```
   <select data-placeholder="Specialty" class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
</select>
```

It is not working when i am using normal show and hide jquery and javascript!

Comment: can u share the complete code??
or a jsfiddle link!!!!

Comment: Shashank, Actually this Chosen Jquery plugin includes many js & css files. if i will show you just one front end page is it okay for you?

Comment: i am using http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ second multi select from this webpage

Comment: It the select initially hidden? If so, then the width of Chosen can't be determined and has to be provided as `width` option in `$().chosen(..)`

Answer (score 0):

To hide on load add style like this

```
   <select data-placeholder="Specialty" class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px; display: none;" tabindex="4"></select>
```

then add this script for click event

```
$('#radio-speciality').click(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $('.chosen-container').show();
  }
  else {
   $('.chosen-container').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry i have edited it.. Try now there was a change in the selector to show or hide

Comment: Manu it is still not working! what might be the reason? have you ever worked with chosen jquery?